# Algolia: Indexing relations - managing data of different shapes

Tags: algolia

The algolia documentation explains two ways to index relations and suggests that option 2 is preferable. All the algolia examples I have seen (including the frontpage movie demo) use option 1.

My question is that, when using option 2 you would receive opbjects of different shapes when doing a query. Is the frontend simply supposed to handle this? Are there any best practices for handling this?

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/formatting-your-data#indexing-relations

Comment: Were you able to solve this?